# Accessing object property defined as constant

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have following `code`:

`constants.js` (defines following `constants`)

```
var STATE_NOT_STARTED = 27;
var STATE_IN_PROGRESS = 28;
var STATE_DEFERRED = 29;
var STATE_CANCELLED = 30;
var STATE_COMPLETED = 31;
```

`app.js` (defines following `object`):

```
var App={

rules: { 
    STATE_NOT_STARTED:[STATE_IN_PROGRESS,STATE_COMPLETED,STATE_CANCELLED,STATE_DEFERRED],
    STATE_IN_PROGRESS: [STATE_COMPLETED,STATE_CANCELLED,STATE_DEFERRED],
    STATE_DEFERRED: [STATE_IN_PROGRESS],
    STATE_CANCELLED:  [STATE_IN_PROGRESS],
    STATE_COMPLETED: [STATE_IN_PROGRESS] 
   }

}
```

Now I have a function in which I get a value. The value can be in either 27,28,29,30 or 31. 
I want to get the rule's specific index based on value I got like this:

```
function execute(value)
{
   App.rules[value]//This returns undefined, even if the value is 27,28,29,30 or 31

}
```

Why I am getting `undefined` with the statement `App.rules[value]`. 
As per bracket notation I should be able to retrieve the `object` `key` like that.

Note:
It does not work even if I do it like this: `App.rules[STATE_NOT_STARTED]` or any other constant value. 
It only works like this: `App.rules.STATE_NOT_STARTED` but since the value is dynamic I am not sure what value parameter holds while passed to a function

Comment: For constants you should use `const` ...

Comment: Currently using ES5 @JonasW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`App.rules.STATE_NOT_STARTED !== STATE_NOT_STARTED // from constants.js`

You want to do :

```
var App={

rules: { 
    [STATE_NOT_STARTED]:[STATE_IN_PROGRESS,STATE_COMPLETED,STATE_CANCELLED,STATE_DEFERRED],
    [STATE_IN_PROGRESS]: [STATE_COMPLETED,STATE_CANCELLED,STATE_DEFERRED],
    [STATE_DEFERRED]: [STATE_IN_PROGRESS],
    [STATE_CANCELLED]:  [STATE_IN_PROGRESS],
    [STATE_COMPLETED]: [STATE_IN_PROGRESS] 
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works good. Can you explain a bit why indexes should be wrapped in square brackets?

Comment: @Hammad `var A = 45, var o = { A : 1};` creates {A: 1}, because that's the syntax for creating a literal object. When you want to create dynamic keys on a literal object, you have to write it differently, and insteald do : `o = { [A] : 1 }` which will give { 45: 1 } more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: Thank you very much for answer and giving links to documentation as well.